# Save File And Json Data Via Angular and Spring boot

Tags: mysql, json, angular, spring-boot, file-upload

i have had this bug for a long peroid now, was trying to figure it out myself but am not getting it, it's an angular/spring boot app that am trying to upload different files and also save a json data at the same time, i have gone through previous questions concerning it but it hasn't worked for me, but when i tried saving the data via postman it works perfectly but not the same with angular, please i will appreciate the assistance...
this is my component.ts file containing the function

```
addBeat(artWork: File,untaggedmp3:File, taggedmp3:File){
    const formData:FormData = new FormData();
    if(artWork){
      formData.append('artWork', artWork)
    }
    if(untaggedmp3){
      formData.append('untaggedmp3', untaggedmp3)
    }
    if(taggedmp3){
      formData.append('taggedmp3', taggedmp3)
    }
    this.beat.name = this.addBeatForm.get('name').value;
    this.beat.price = this.addBeatForm.get('price').value;
    this.beat.tempo = this.addBeatForm.get('tempo').value;
    this.beat.description = this.addBeatForm.get('description').value;
    this.beat.beatKey = this.addBeatForm.get('beatKey').value;
    this.beat.mood = this.addBeatForm.get('mood').value;
    this.beat.genre = this.addBeatForm.get('genre').value;
    formData.append('beatDto', JSON.stringify(this.beat));
    this.beatService.uploadBeat(formData)
    .subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
    
  }
```

And my service.ts

```
public uploadBeat(formData: FormData): Observable<BeatDto>{
    return this.httpClient.post<BeatDto>(`${this.apiServerUrl.admin}/api/beat/single/upload`, formData,
{headers: {
      'Accept':'multipart/form-data',
      'mimeType': 'multipart/form-data'}}
    ));
  }
```

and  my springboot rest controller is this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/beat")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BeatController {
    
    private final BeatService beatService;
    private final FileStorageService fileStorageService;
    @PostMapping(path = "/single/upload", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<BeatDto> uploadBeat(@RequestParam("beatDto") String beatDto, 
            @RequestParam("artWork") MultipartFile artWork,
            @RequestParam("taggedmp3") MultipartFile taggedmp3,
            @RequestParam("untaggedmp3") MultipartFile untaggedmp3){
        BeatDto beatJson = beatService.getJson(beatDto,artWork,taggedmp3,untaggedmp3);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(beatService.uploadBeat(beatJson,artWork,taggedmp3,untaggedmp3));
    }
}
```

so when i test in on the browser i get a error code 400 on the browser console...

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "http://localhost:8081/api/beat/single/upload",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:8081/api/beat/single/upload: 400 OK",
    "error": null
}
```

And also from my network tab

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8081/api/beat/single/upload
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: [::1]:8081
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 06 Jan 2022 02:02:41 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Accept: multipart/form-data
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 638
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFUAjEynxdkQfpcfA
Host: localhost:8081
mimeType: multipart/form-data
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

main.app

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@Import(SwaggerConfiguration.class)
public class BasicApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicApplication.class, args);
    }
        
        @Bean
        public CorsFilter corsFilter(){
            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(3600L);
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
        }
}
```

security config

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/assests/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/beat/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/beat/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you try to use @RequestPart instead of @RequestParam? 
Also why Content-Type header is false, also your 400 response statusText is OK which is ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry ignore my above comment, I could reproduce and it works for me. Can you try to mimic this 
`var form = new FormData();
form.append("beatDto", "hello");
form.append("artWork", fileInput.files[0], "hgello.txt");
form.append("taggedmp3", fileInput.files[0], "hgello.txt");
form.append("untaggedmp3", fileInput.files[0], "hgello.txt");

var settings = {
  "url": "localhost:8080/upload",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "multipart/form-data",
  },
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
};`

Comment: @memoricab thanks for replying but still no way through,

Comment: At some point when i changed some lines on my front end, i was getting this cors error message on the browser console

Comment: i have added my backend config and also tried changing between requestpart and requestparam, still the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with Angular and Spring Boot, here some snippets that should help you.
At first you need to transfer the data in Angular as a multi-form data like this. We create a blob and set a content-type for it.
I have this in my service:

```js
  create(info: Info, doc1: File | null, doc2: File | null, doc3: File | null, doc4: File | null) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data', new Blob([JSON.stringify(info)], {
      type: 'application/json',
    }));
    if (doc1)
      formData.append("doc1", doc1);
    if (doc2)
      formData.append("doc2", doc2);
    if (doc3)
      formData.append("doc3", doc3);
    if (doc4)
      formData.append("doc4", doc4);
    return this.http.post<WorkRequest>('api/wr', formData);
  }
```

After you subscribed to the observable a POST request will be send to the server. You can check in the developer tools of your browser how it looks like.

To handle the request on the server I expect you have your entity defined that matches the format of the json data you send. In my controller I use now:

```java
    @PostMapping(path = WorkRequestLinks.LIST_WORK_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createRequest(
            @RequestPart(name = "data") WRequest wRequest,
            @RequestParam(name = "doc1", required = false) MultipartFile doc1,
            @RequestParam(name = "doc2", required = false) MultipartFile doc2,
            @RequestParam(name = "doc3", required = false) MultipartFile doc3,
            @RequestParam(name = "doc4", required = false) MultipartFile doc4) {
        log.debug("WRequestController: create WRequest");
        WRequest resource = wRequestService.create(wRequest);
        log.debug("Add files");
...
```

You will find in wRequest already an object that was automatically parsed from the json string and mapped to the format your entity is defined, so can hand it over to a service to persist it to a database.

The uploaded files you can handle as everywhere described in detail, I will repeat it here again.